# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'css')

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am facing this issue while integrating PrimeFaces with existing JSF application. I am trying to integrate editor of PrimeFaces. Below is the code based:

```html
<html>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<t:div rendered="#{model.mimeType == 'application/rtf'}" forceId="true" id="rtfEditor">
    <p:editor id="editor" widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{editorView.text}" width="1000" height="500" />
</t:div>
</html>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'css')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:337:9081)
    at i (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25:25791)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25:26797)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25:28871)
    at HTMLDocument.bY (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25:29263)
```

Using below version:
Jdk:8
JSF: 2.2
PrimeFaces: 6.1

Some search results suggested to make sure the jQuery plugin exist, I can view the jQuery is bound with PrimeFaces plugin.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you include multiple versions of jQuery? When do you get that error? Have you tried without including `h:outputScript` and using xhtml with head, for PF?

Comment: I didn't include multiple jQuery versions. I am getting this error while page loading. I tried without h:outputScript, but it still the same.